# How to check internet connection in Fragement Tabs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app in which i want to check if internet connection is there then it will execute the task otherwise it will show error message like no internet connection is there.In this application i am using 2 tabs. I wrote one code for checking internet connection,but every time when no connection is there my app crashes.

Code for Main Activity:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Internet Connection is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else {


        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

                if (key.equals("Tab_Notification") && value.equals("True")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab_Notification.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value", value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        }

        subscribeToPushService();



   final Handler mHandler = new Handler();


   final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 15000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

            }

        }, delay, period);


        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(SignIn.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      final String e = sharedpreferences.getString(SignIn.email, "");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout1);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
        i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pinButton);
        i.setOnClickListener(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Super Market"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Shopping"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("FOOD"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Cosmetics"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Medical"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Hotels"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Jewellery"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapterClass(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab LayoutTab) {

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(LayoutTab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab LayoutTab) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab LayoutTab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Tab1 code:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {


                getData();

                upcomingJobs.clear();
                upcomingJobs.addAll(upcomingJobs);
                // fire the event
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                // uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


    });
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    getData();

    return v;
}


private void getData() {
    class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            // progressDialog.dismiss();
            parseJSON(s);


            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {



            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Config.GET_URL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }

                return sb.toString().trim();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }


    }
    GetData gd = new GetData();
    gd.execute();
}

public void showData() {
    adapter = new CardAdapter(Config.offer, Config.offerprice, Config.bitmaps, Config.price, Config.urls);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Card at " + position + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
}


private void parseJSON(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        config = new Config(array.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Config.offer[i] = getoffer(j);
            Config.urls[i] = geturl(j);
            Config.offerprice[i] = getofferprice(j);
            Config.price[i] = getprice(j);
            Config.urls[i] = geturl(j);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GetBitmap gb = new GetBitmap(getContext(), this, Config.urls);
    gb.execute();
}

private String getoffer(JSONObject j) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = j.getString(Config.TAG_Offer);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

private String getofferprice(JSONObject j) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = j.getString(Config.TAG_Offerprice);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

private String getprice(JSONObject j) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = j.getString(Config.TAG_price);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}


private String geturl(JSONObject j) {
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = j.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                    at com.zaps.myrewards.Tab_1_Activity.parseJSON(Tab_1_Activity.java:144)
                                                                    at com.zaps.myrewards.Tab_1_Activity.access$300(Tab_1_Activity.java:31)
                                                                    at com.zaps.myrewards.Tab_1_Activity$1GetData.onPostExecute(Tab_1_Activity.java:92)
                                                                    at com.zaps.myrewards.Tab_1_Activity$1GetData.onPostExecute(Tab_1_Activity.java:78)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: check my updated code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new class Application_utlity (according to u) and put this code in your class like that

```
public class Application_utility {

ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
NetworkInfo info;

public boolean checkConnection(Context context) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {

        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

            System.out.println(info.getTypeName());
            flag = true;
        }

        if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            System.out.println(info.getTypeName());
            flag = true;
        }

    } catch (Exception exception) {

        System.out.println("Exception at network connection....."
                + exception);
    }

   return flag;
}}
```

if u want to check your internet connection in fragment then use method check connection in fragment like :

```
final boolean checkConnection=new Application_utility().checkConnection(getActivity());

if(!checkConnection)
{

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

else{

// your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by passing your fragment context or parent activity.

```
 /**
 * Check Connection
 *
 * @param ctx
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return ni != null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected();
}
```